# Click a text link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to click the link found at the bottom of this [page](http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/categories/computer) with the text "Show more companies".

I tried these two ways so far:

```
    $('a:contains("Show more companies")').click();
    $('a:contains("Show more companies")').trigger('click');
```

but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object <a class="button AjaxPagerLink" href="http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/categories/computer?page=2">
Show more companies </a> has no method 'click' at Request._callback (C:\app.js:42:43)
```

Any clues what the problem is? Is my command correct? Any advice/help is really appreciated.

Edit: Tried all these solutions. Getting the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery

Comment: $().click() method binds the click event to an event handler, that is the argument of the click() method. You have specified no handler in your code. Please refer to the jQuery docs here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I was able to see more companies in chrome without any errors.

Comment: It is working. check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJpj/12/)

Comment: Murali, it doesn't on my app. i know that it was suppose to run but when i run it using node js i get this error. Yes i have installed jquery and used it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Triggering the class should be easy, but you should verify (it seems so) that there is just an element with that class name.

```
$(".AjaxPagerLink").trigger("click");
```

This second version triggers the first class="AjaxPagerLink" element on that page, just to  take a wild guess.

```
$(".AjaxPagerLink")[0].trigger("click");
```

You can also try a [href^="http"] CSS selector.

```
$("a[href^='http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/categories/computer?page']").trigger("click");
```

---

In general:

Using classes and IDs to retrieve DOM elements is a best practice (as it's also faster than parsing the contained text).

```
<a href='companies.html' id='show_companies'>Show more companies</a>
```

You should assign an ID to the  element and then trigger a click on that ID:

```
$('#show_companies').trigger('click');
```

Just make sure your ID is unique (there must be only a show_companies element in your page).

Comment: he posted this under web-scraping so I dont think he can change the html.

Comment: Thank you @user2932397, I really missed that tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a.button.AjaxPagerLink').click();
```

this is better than selecting based on the text.

**EDIT**: if that is not the issue, then make sure you are calling `.click()` after you have registered a onClickListener for that link.

Comment: he posted under web-scraping so I dont think he can change the page to have an onClickListener.

Comment: no I mean he can make sure that he calls `click()` only after a Listener has been registered.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. so make sure his code is running after the page's listener has been registered?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    $('a:contains("Show more companies")').click(function(){
         var link = $(this).attr('href');
         window.location.href = link;   
    }
```

Comment: that link is ajax, doing this would defeat its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

$('a:contains("Show more companies")')[0].click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('a:contains("Show more companies")')[0].click();
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'click'

Comment: I opened firebug on the page you linked, and pasted this exact code in to the console and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a:contains("Show more companies")').click(function () {
            alert('I am clicked');
        });
    });
```

Comment: this is not what he is asking for. he wants to fire the click handler on that page, not create his own handler.