# jquery trigger for href not working

Tags: jquery

As soon as the page load, href link should get trigger(Manual click should not happen).Plz help

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="info">Information</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#info").click(function(){

  });
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#info").trigger("click");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: First I'm not sure the window load event fires when inside a document ready event. Second, I'm unsure if the click event is defined for a link. If you fleshed out the click handler you're adding to it you could trigger it. Better yet, `window.location.href="www.google.com";`

Comment: And this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery

Comment: Manual click should not happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#info").on("click",function(){
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
       $(location).attr('href',url);
    });
    $("#info").trigger("click");
    });
    </script>
```

Jsffidle demo  http://jsfiddle.net/waseemmachloy/tBGX3/2/

Comment: Manual clicking should never happen

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried your jsfiddle,in that on loading a page its not going to google(www.google.com) but by manual clicking its triggering to google.

Comment: yes because there  was alert function(to clear you whats happening ) , i update the code and jsfiddle link now please check

Comment: you are welcome , if its work  accept the answer by clicking  the tick on left side of my answer:)

Comment: I want to be reload only once instead of reloading many times.plz help

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the event as follows

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="info">Information</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#info").click(function(){
         alert('clicked');
     }).trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need empty click handler for anchor. Just use:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#info").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#info").click(function(){
    alert()
  });
  $("#info").click()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just redirecting with JQuery?

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Manual click is not encouraged

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
$(function(){
  $("#info")[0].click();
});
```