# How to call a click( ) attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function dosomething(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')+' called with '+$(this).innerHTML);
}
$('#myElement').click(dosomething);
```

here is the HTML:

```
<div id="myElement">click me</div>
```

Clicking the element works.  But the following call from another location does not:

```
dosomething($('#myElement'));
```

Working with objects in Javascript is still frustrating to me.  Can anyone explain WHY #2 doesn't work, and an elegant way to handle both cases?  here is a jsfiddle for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/sqb6bkwr/

Comment: `$('#myElement').trigger('click');`

Comment: Or `$('#myElement').click();`

Comment: @Travesty3 Not to be an ass, but mine is better by 0.00000001ms :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Comment: google it first before you post here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dosomething($('#myElement'));
```

This doesn't work because the function `dosomething()` is not expecting the element to be taken in as the first parameter, and passing it as a parameter does not automatically set it as `this`.

The way you *should* call that method depends on your intended behavior. If what you want is to just call that `dosomething` function on that element, then you can do this:

```
dosomething.call($('#myElement')[0]);
```

But if your objective is to simulate a click on that element, which would trigger any other click event listeners that may be on that element, then you should do this:

```
$('#myElement').click();
// or, as @Karl-AndréGagnon pointed out, $('#myElement').trigger('click');
```

The difference may seem small, but knowing what you really want to happen will probably save you from some headaches down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `dosomething()` does not accept any arguments. Therefor it will not work. You can choose to use `$('#myElemenet').trigger('click');`, <del>or choose to have your function accept an argument which sets the element:</del>

```
function dosomething(el) {
    el = (el) ? el : $(this);
    alert(el.attr('id')+' called with '+el.innerHTML);
}

// My suggestion won't work.
// Use dosomething.call(el) instead.
```

Comment: That will not work because `el` when physically clicking the element will be the event. so `el.attr()` will throw `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I stand corrected :-). In that case I'd go with `.call()` as suggested by Zenorbi.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `this` value of your function was not set. You pass an argument to your function, but expect the `this` value to be the argument.

You should instead call that like this:
`dosomething.call($("#myelement")[0]);`

This will call the function with the `this` value of the `#myelement`. The `[0]` is there because you want the native DOM element, not a jQuery array-like object. This is why you wrap the `this` in `$(this)` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var domething;
$(document).ready(function(){
dosomething = function(elem){
    alert(elem.attr('id')+' called with '+elem.attr('title'));
}
$('#myElement').click(function(){
  dosomething($(this));
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/3z0pg9b1/1/