# How to trigger a click on a list with many list items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please note that I want to use JQuery for this.
This question [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery) provided a solution for when only one anchor exists inside the list

However I have more than one list item and more than one anchor.

```
<ul id="navigation_list">
  <li id="sub_menu1_tab" style="">
    <span class="decorator"></span>
    <a id="policies" href="#admin/menu1_list" class="admin-submenu-item"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="sub_menu2_tab" style="">
    <span class="decorator"></span>
    <a id="rules" href="#admin/menu2_list" class="admin-submenu-item"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="sub_menu3_tab" style="">
    <span class="decorator"></span>
    <a id="reports" href="#admin/menu3_list" class="admin-submenu-item"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I trigger a click on only one of the anchors? For example I want to trigger the second list item anchor.
I have tried the following without success

```
$("#sub_menu2_tab a").trigger('click');
```

and

```
$("#navigation_list #sub_menu2_tab a").trigger('click');
```

Comment: are you sure the issue is with the .trigger()? it works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epc3paop/)

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
$("#sub_menu2_tab a").click();
```

Comment: I actually had tried the .click() version also. This didn't work for me either. I am suspecting that either this has to do with the anchor being inside a li that's inside a ul or some deeper issue with my code I am missing. Thanks though.

Comment: @snowleopard what do u get when call `$("#sub_menu2_tab a")` ? can you inspect your browser console?