# Bootstrap 5 scrollspy when accessing from another page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, scrollspy

This was a question previously here [Bootstrap scrollspy when accessing from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721431/bootstrap-scrollspy-when-accessing-from-another-page)

But that's jquery and I converted it to Javascript but is not working for me. Can you guys help me, please?

```
  fixScrollSpy() {
    var stripped_url = window.location.toString().split("#");
    if (stripped_url.length > 1) {
      var activeId = "#nav-deep-" + stripped_url[1];
      activeId.addEventListener("click", () => {});
    }
  }
```

And also like this but none of them worked

```
  fixScrollSpy() {
    var stripped_url = window.location.toString().split("#");
    if (stripped_url.length > 1) {
      var activeId = "#nav-deep-" + stripped_url[1];
      document.querySelector(activeId)[0].click();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Its better if you can specify what part is not working, what error sre you getting, etc