# Firing the onclick event for a specific href

Tags: jquery

In the code of my page there are many href. I want to execute the onclick function for a specific href:

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; width: 90px;"> text <a href="http://www.domain.com/example" target="_blank"> click here </a></div>
```

General option:

```
$('a').on("click", function(variable) {}
```

Comment: what is that specific href?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy http://www.domain.com/example

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Comment: `$('a[href*="domain.com/example"]').click()`  or in a most specific way you could use it like  `$('a[href$="domain.com/example"]').click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[Attribute Equals Selector [name=value]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

```
$('a[href="http://www.domain.com/example"]').on("click", function(ev) {
   //click handler for anchor      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a specific class name or id to the href that you want to bind the action to.

For example:

```
<a id="this_is_the_one" href="http://www.domain.com/example" target="_blank"> click here </a>
```

and then your js:

```
$('#this_is_the_one').on("click", function(variable) {}
```