# Trigger event doesn't fire in ie11

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to simulate a click when a page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('ul.dk_options_inner li:nth-child(2) a').trigger('click');
 });
 </script>
```

It works in all browsers apart from IE11. Are there any alternatives to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can try to reproduce the issue. Are you getting any errors in IE?

Comment: Just getting the issue in ie11. I will try and put the code together.