# What is the difference between $('#id').trigger('click') and document.getElementById('id').click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I am writing a tampermonkey script on chrome to simulate a mouse click and find that only `document.getElementById('id').click()` trigger the correct behaviour.

The expected behaviour is to show and hide a date-picker. With `$('#id').trigger('click')` I can only hide the date-picker. I do not think I should add more details because that may just add more confusion.

The page is Telerik based, so I have not found an easy way to simplify the page and isolate the issue.

### Update:

Here is the DOM code

```
<a title="Open the calendar popup." href="#" id="id" class="rcCalPopup">
    Open the calendar popup.
</a>
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334234/529187) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery#comment39194073_5811465), it looks like `a` or the content of `a` is causing this issue.

> This is all about what you are clicking and it is not the tag but the thing within it. Unfortunately, **bare text does not seem to be recognised by JQuery**, but it is by vanilla javascript.

Can anyone help confirm this?

### Update 2:

I have created a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pdy5b4jv/8/). It is not ideal, because I have to add dependency of Telerik to reproduce the issue.

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#id')[0].click(); // Show the date-picker
        document.getElementById('id').click(); // Hide the date-picker
        $('#id').trigger('click'); // Not working, should show the date-picker again. Tried for <button> and it worked fine.
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You need to post all the code relative to this mysterious `#id`. For all we know the error is just a simple syntax problem (not to insult you or your coding capabilities), so we need to see _all_ the relevant code.

Comment: `$('#id').trigger('click')` seems to work as expected see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/jjcsh76w/1/ . You're question is about *how to show and hide a date-picker using $('#id').trigger('click')* but you dont show us any of that code. Youll need to show us the datepicker code or make a jsfiddle so we can see the issue. \

Comment: Hi @DelightedD0D, my question is about the difference between `trigger('click')` and `click()`. That is way I am reluctant to add more unrelated details. I have managed to solve the problem of showing the date-picker, but wonder why one solution did not work.

Comment: Sure, but if we dont see the issue, it's going to be hard to explain it, right? This could well be an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) , context matters

Comment: Thanks @DelightedD0D. I have created a jsfiddle and updated the question.