# Javascript DOM Click button with no onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am programming a script that should click buttons on a website, which dont have a onclick event. for example:

```
<button class="button exButton but">Example</button>
```

I try to automate them so you don't have to click them all by yourself, i am trying to figure out how i can click them in javascript. 
First of all `document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click` doesn't work

I hope you guys can help me!


Greetz Julian

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName("button")[0].click` you aren't calling that function.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @dandavis `button` is also a class name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript), also a duplicate of [How to Trigger a Click Using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery).  What you want to do is `$('.button').trigger('click')`, but since your button may not even have a click handler it's doubtful it will do anything.  To rephrase, since there is no "onclick" event, clicking them is **supposed** to do nothing.  Here's the "correct" answer: `;`

Comment: @Xufox: good eye; both should work

Comment: so first off all, thanks for all the replies, but i got the spelling right, it was just a spelling mistake in the question ^^ thanksto @Tibrogargan for the question links o/

Comment: If the DOM is loaded and you’re using `document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click();`, it _should_ work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using JQUERY .trigger() function .

```
$( "button.exButton" ).trigger( "click" );
```

A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user: