# How to click a Button By matching a text.?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am very New to JavaScript. Now i am trying to make a Google Chrome Extension which a click a Button on a specific web address. But the Site opens only for 30 second.. So i just saw the button color is GREEN and the button text is- " Move To "
so how can i trigger that button ? I am Trying for this. But its not Working.

```
var b = $('button[class*="Move To"]')[1]
       $(b).click();
```

Comment: The `[class]` attribute selector, unsurprisingly, selects by the class attribute - not the text.

Comment: How to get that ? As i can't go for the page whenever i want. It becomes active only for 30-40 second .. So is it possible to trigger anyway ?

Comment: @Ruhul answer will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:contains`.

```
var b = $( "button:contains('Move To')" )[1]
b.trigger('click');
```

> https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Or if text is exactly `Move To` you can use this:

```
var b;
if($('button').text() == 'Target'){
    $('button').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: He is talking about text not a class

Comment: My question is can i trigger a Button Just by its Text ?

Comment: @MohammadReza .. Thanks. I got it .

Answer (score 0):

fire click event on a button containing particular text

js

```
$("button:contains('Move To')").trigger( "click" );
```

HTML

```
<button id="btn">Move To</button>
```

Comment: So it will trigger that button which contains text "Move To ".. Right ?

Comment: Ideally, yes. Rather simply try this $("button:contains('Move To')").trigger( "click" );

Comment: Thanks.  I will ..  :)

Comment: @ArifRubayet : Please mark it as answered, if it solves your problem.

Comment: . one more question If i want to trigger A link text.. Like 

going www.google.com then at the top you can see ( Gmail ) how to click that on ? its not button type.  So what is it ?  Sorry i am trying to mark your ans Up.. but system saying My reputation is Below 15. what to do !!!

Comment: It can be achieved in a similar way,  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery