# Trigger click on a tag when pressing fake read more button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Structure is as following:

```
div
  h1
    a
  p
  .more-info
```

When I click on .more-info div I need to simulate a click on the 'a'.

```
 $(".more-info").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('h1').find('a').get(0).trigger('click');
 })
```

This gives following error:

```
$(...).parent(...).find(...).find(...).get(...).trigger is not a function
```

Output of

```
 console.log($(this).parent().find('h1').find('a').get(0))
```

is the correct element I need to click.

I've tried without .get(0) and get following when I log that

```
 [a, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: p.more-info, selector: "h1 a"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.get(0)` returns the DOM element within the jQuery object, but `.trigger()` is a jQuery function, so it needs to operate on the jQuery object.

But if you're trying to emulate the browser's built-in action when clicking on a link, `.trigger()` won't do it. You need to call the DOM element's `.click()` method.

```
 $(".more-info").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('h1').find('a').get(0).click();
 });
```

See [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Comment: the .get(0) was a desperate attempt because it didn't work without it either. Nothing happens and when I log it I get the correct element. For some reason the click is just not working. Even when I copy selector from elements directly and .trigger('click') or .click() it does nothing.

Comment: Note that `.click()` does not trigger the browser's built-in click handling, it only runs the jQuery handler. So it won't follow the link in the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the element's .click() method, but I would recommend putting a link on the more-info element itself.

Anyhow, this should work:

`$(this).parent().find('h1 > a').get(0).click();`

Check out the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lpyctuga/4/

Comment: the .get(0) was a desperate attempt because it didn't work without it either. Nothing happens and when I log it I get the correct element. For some reason the click is just not working. Even when I copy selector from elements directly and .trigger('click') or .click() it does nothing.

Comment: When I log when clicking with $(this).parent().find('h1 > a').click();

I get following  [a, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: p.more-info, selector: "h1 > a"]

Comment: That means he cannot find the a-element. Are you sure the HTML structure is as provided or not another element was found with the $('.more-info') selector?

Comment: Here's an example in vanilla JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpyctuga/

Comment: And here with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpyctuga/1/  Turns out you better do use .get(0) because triggering a click on the element collection can give issues.