# Automatic JQuery Click Event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to code a click event to automatically occur after I

```
1. select an option from a dropdown.
2. depending on the option, the text of the option gets set as the value of a textbox.
2. set focus into the textbox.
```

What is working is the textbox value gets set and the cursor gets positioned into the textbox at the end of the text.  But I can't figure out how to automate a click event to get the cursor to move to the next field.

I tried using focusin as show below...

```
<script>     
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#textbox").focusin(function() {
            jQuery("#textbox").trigger('click');
        });
    });  
</script>
```

And when I include an alert, in the function, the alert popups to show that I'm in the focusin function, but I can't seem to get the click to work.  And the alert just keeps re-popping up.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334234/2295034

Comment: I added a click function but still doesn't work.

Comment: can you post a working example?

Comment: I got it to work with a blur event