# 'too much recursion' error when firing click() command on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I want to click on the div and have it fire a `click()` on the specified element ID, however I'm getting this recursion error instead, like it's in an infinite loop.

```js
function clickLink(id) {
  $('#' + id).click();
}
```

```css
.theDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

click the div, but not on the link
<div class="theDiv" onclick="clickLink('linkId')">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="linkId">i am a link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your problem is the bubbling check this: https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/event-bubbling-and-event-capturing-in-javascript-6ff38bec30e   
Aside from that, I have the feeling that you can accomplish wherever you are looking for without doing this. Try to style the `a` with `display:block`

Comment: I explained what I'm wanting to achieve. Have an onclick event on the div that fires the link inside it.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Have you tried my updated answer? I was able to recreate your problem and solve it.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact an infinite loop because of event bubbling. Events that occur on the child elements will bubble up to parents. In your case click that occurs on the `a#linkId` will bubble to the parent `div` and trigger the `onclick` handler ("clicking" the `a#linkId` again).

Comment: *free hint:* what OP is trying to achieve is a click router. So that wherever you click, inside the div, it does trigger the anchor click. For this to happen, the cleanest way might actually be to wrap the div inside the anchor. But otherwise, it is very well possible to look at the event.target and decide if the routing should occur or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function clickLink(id) {
    $('#' + id)[0].click();
}
```

There may still be recursion, but the problem is your click function isn't working. Since we're leaving the page (clicking a link to google.com), it doesn't really matter.

For explanation on the click event see Roman Starkov's comment:
[How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery#comments-5811122)

Comment: The link definitely needs to be inside the div.

Comment: @DanielWilliams updated my answer. And why does it need to be in the div?

Comment: Will still trigger twice if the click occurred on the `<a>`.

Comment: I did some further testing and saw no evidence of it being clicked twice (I tried console logging and alerts).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've actually abandoned this idea and am just doing an onclick for the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the trigger from jquery

```
function clickLink(id) {
  $('#' + id).trigger(”click”);
}
```