# Clicking the Next Link

Tags: jquery

I want to click on a pagination link at the bottom **which is the next to** `<td class="cur">`. In this case, "Pg 2".

```
<td class="cur"><a aria-label="Pg 1" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Pg 2" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
```

Then again on Page 2, click on a link which is the next to `<td class="cur">`. In this case, "Pg 3".

```
<td><a aria-label="Pg 1" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
<td class="cur"><a aria-label="Pg 2" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Pg 3" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
```

and so on.

How do I implement this in JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Can you more clarify what you ask please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table has an ID ('tableName'), this should work fine:

```
var nextButton= $('#nav td.cur > a.pg')
               .parent() // go to the parent td
               .next() // vist next td sibling
               .find('a.pg'); // find a inside of this td sibling
    nextButton.trigger('click');
```

You can find examples of trigger method [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery).

Comment: If my table has a tbody and a tr containing all these td's, does the selector change? I tried the above, gave it the table id but nothing happens. I even tried this alert($('#nav td.cur > a.pg').attr('href')); which returned undefined.