# Programatically Invoke jquery datatable cell click event

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to invoke a mouse click event with out clicking in jquery datatable programatically.

In the initial load my table will have a empty row with default values. I have written a event like

```
$("#demoGrid").on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
});
```

I need to invoke this on document.ready() method. Is it Possible? i want the click should happen in the **second column of first row column** as well. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery

Comment: Its a datatable we need to tell which which row and which column to be clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last i Got it

```
$('#demoGrid tbody td:eq(2)').click();
```