# How to trigger an element clicking on another element

Tags: jquery, triggers, touchstart

i have a problem with a mobile menu, i want an element to get triggered when i click on the menu links my code works perfectly when tested on desktop browsers but not in mobile browser

this is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery(".menu-item > a").on("click touchstart", function(){
       jQuery(".hamburger-box").click();
   });


});
```

Comment: that selector is naaaasty!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your jquery selector right;you can use `Jquery("selector").trigger("click");`

Comment: jQuery(".menu-item > a").on("click touchstart", function(){
       console.log(jQuery(".hamburger-box"))
   }); log to console and after look do you find right elements

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this,

jQuery('.hamburger-box').trigger('touchstart');