# Detecting if a 'a href' exists using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using this script to find an `a href` within a parent element and then go to that link if the parent div is clicked.

```
jQuery(".card").click(function() {
  window.location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
```

However, I am finding that if there is no `a href` at all, it is still adding a link to 'undefined' (resulting in 404).

I am fairly certain I need an `if` to detect if there is an `a href`, but cannot get it to work:

```
jQuery(".card").click(function() {
     if (jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href").length {
  window.location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know what are all your requirements, but I would assume that by just calling a click on the hyperlink you would achieve the same result, with the bonus of not doing anything if the hyperlink isn't available.

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis after `length`

Comment: looks like he wants the entire div to behave like the anchor's link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a click on a link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to check to see if the `a` exists via length.

```
jQuery(".card a",function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("has-link");
})

jQuery(".card.has-link").click(function() {
  window.location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Is there a simple way I can also add a class of 'has-link' to those items that have an href?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.